# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' in VS code

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, pip, module

I have installed numpy using pip
also the same code below works smoothly in python IDLE but not in vs code

[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqS7d.png)

I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
np.ones(8)
```

and the error shows:

```
PS C:\Users\anshu\Documents\VScode Python> python -u "c:\Users\anshu\Documents\VScode Python\extra.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\anshu\Documents\VScode Python\extra.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
PS C:\Users\anshu\Documents\VScode Python>
```

i have checked many questions and they usually say install numpy using, `pip install numpy`.
or there is a things in another IDEs like anaconda (which i do not install) or pycharm etc.

i just wanted to resolve this problem in vs code not in any other IDE.

Comment: Did you try installing `pip install numpy` in __*VS Code*__?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `python -u file` I would suggest checking the python you're using is the same one you installed numpy to, it could be using a different installation.

Many users often have several python installations or virtual environments (more on that here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) and that can cause conflicts in aliases and required dependencies and where they are installed.

I'd recommend ensuring you install numpy to same installation you're running from, to do that you can do:
`python -m pip install numpy`

See here for more information about using pip for a certain python installation: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#running-pip

Comment: did not work buddy

Comment: @AnshulSangwan Have you checked the interpreter the IDE is using then?


For VS:Code It would be in the bottom right if you press it, it should show a list of all installations found and if applicable any virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.

You could try to use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter which you installed the package in.